# Unable to get a covered query to use index only in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongoid

I am trying to use a covering index to implement stemming text search on my app which uses mongodb.

I've got the following index set:

```
ensureIndex({st: 1, n: 1, _id: 1});
```

But when I run explain() on my query, I can never get the indexOnly to read true, no matter what I do.

```
db.merchants.find({st: "Blue"}, {n:1,_id:1}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor st_1_n_1__id_1",
    "nscanned" : 8,
    "nscannedObjects" : 8,
    "n" : 8,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "st" : [
            [
                "Blue",
                "Blue"
            ]
        ],
        "n" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "_id" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I've already figured out that the ordering of the keys in the index matter somehow. For instance if I used {_id, n:1, st:1} it wasn't using this index at all to perform the query. I also read somewhere that too few documents could trigger unpredictable behaviour with explain() since multiple strategies are equally fast. But in this case, I see that its using the right index, but its not using just the index. What is this happening?

I am using mongoid, and mongo 2.0.8 I believe.

UPDATE:

Switched over to using Mongoid v3.1.4 and mongod v2.2

Here is the query that mongod is seeing from mongoid: Mon Jul 15 10:47:26 [conn14] runQuery called spl_development.merchants { $query: { st: { $regex: "cr", $options: "i" } }, $explain: true } Mon Jul 15 10:47:26 [conn14] query spl_development.merchants query: { $query: { st: { $regex: "cr", $options: "i" } }, $explain: true } ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:212 nreturned:1 reslen:393 0ms

So the projection isn't being sent to the mongod layer and only just handles it in the application layer. Not ideal!

This has been recognized as a bug in mongoid and can be tracked here:
https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/3142

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I expect your query cannot use a covered index because you have a field with an array included in the index.  This is suggested in the explain with `"isMultiKey" : true`.

As noted in the documentation ([Create Indexes that Support Covered Queries](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#indexes-covered-queries)):

> MongoDB cannot use a covered query if any of the indexed fields in any of the documents in the collection includes an array. If an indexed field is an array, the index becomes a multi-key index and cannot support a covered query.

Comment: Thanks Stennie, thats exactly right, 'st' is an Array. I guess to implement this and ensure that its a covered query for speed, I have to use regex on the text field, while my earlier strategy was that I had split the text into words in an Array. Hopefully the slowness of the regex will be compensated by the fact that the result is returned from the in memory index.

Comment: You could use regular expressions to make this a covered query, but for efficient index use the regex should be left-rooted (eg `/^Blue/`) and case sensitive. Check the `nscanned` value when you add your regex to see the number of index comparisons required versus `n` (the number of results returned). You could also make this a covered query by separating the keyword arrays into multiple documents with a single indexed field.  I would benchmark the different approaches to see what works best for your use case; a multikey (but non-covered index) may actually be fine :)

Comment: Also note that an improved text search feature (stemming, scoring, phrase matching, stop words, .. ) is being worked on for MongoDB 2.4 (see [SERVER-380](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-380)).  You should be able to test this in the upcoming 2.3.2 development release (or nightly builds if you are impatient/curious).  Blog post from someone trying this out: [MongoDB Text Search Explained](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/01/text-search-mongodb-stemming/).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in 2.2.2, but add `.sort({n: 1, _id: 1})` into the chain.  Because you're not sorting, you're asking for the docs in whatever `find` order mongo wishes to use, and if that doesn't match the order in the index (`$natural` order, for instance) it still has to read the docs.

```js
db.merchants.find({st: "Blue"}, {n:1,_id:1}).sort({n: 1, _id: 1}).explain()
```

Comment: The order in the index is irrelevant to whether the query is covered.  By definition, a covered query is one where results can be returned using only the indexed fields.

Comment: I know what you're getting at, but when I was looking at this I found that if I added `.sort($natural: 1})` to the chain it caused the explain to return `indexOnly: false` in cases where it would otherwise be true.  Regardless, I'm sure your answer is the real reason so +1 to you!

Comment: If you just add a $natural sort, the query optimizer will likely be picking a `BasicCursor` (table scan) given a small number of documents to compare.  You can use a [`hint()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/hint/) to confirm that a sorted query will still be covered if the correct index is used: `db.merchants.find({st: "Blue"}, {n:1,_id:1}).hint('st_1_n_1__id_1').sort({$natural:1}).explain()`.